# Function by using recursion

Tags: recursion, mips

I want to do a programm that finds the times that happens integers of an array to be less or equal from a specific number. I have to use recursion.
I am thinking of returning 0 when the integer is greater than the number ,and 1 otherwise.
Finally I want to find a way to add all those returns by calling the function again as a recursion.
Please help me !

Do I have to save the return value ($v0) at the stack every time ?

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: codymanix: MIPS is a low level assembly language. Its not in widespread use any more (I believe my teacher said that only Sony still uses it within their Playstation gaming systems).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the beginning of each function call, you call the stack and store necessary values, and at the end of the function (epilogue) you must reset the stack to its position, or you will be restoring invalid variables and data from the stack.

My suggestion would be to pass in the address to your array of bites each call and the count of items in the array and return the iteration number (and right before the recursive call check iteration > array amount, and branch to your epilogue) as well as the total number of occurrences.

Quick thinking through my head is telling me that if you implement it correctly, it should work. I unfortunately don't have the time to write an example of such as of this minute (I have to leave for class shortly), but the theory should be sound. I can look at your code and maybe help out later and/or write a quick example later today.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will try to apply them in my programm and  hope to find the solution !

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of thoughts:

1. Usually, by convention, the value 0 means false; and any other value means true. Just to avoid confusion, you might want to adopt that convention in your code. As you describe your thoughts, it seems truth and falsity have the opposite polarities from the conventional.
2. Perhaps an improvement that should please your instructor: instead of returning 0 or 1 as the result of integer comparison, you might want to consider returning the *arithmetic difference* between the two compared integers. That will give you not only equality (i.e., difference == 0) but also some additional information about the integer members of the array without any increased cost in program complexity or time. I was taught that, all else being equal, the more information a function can return, the better.
3. As to recursion: I do not *think* you have to keep all of the ($v0)s on the stack as long as you remember to accumulate each returned ($v0) in a global variable somewhere. But that's only my opinion at the moment, without having looked at the problem.

HTH. I have to say that this is a very nice, small, manageable introduction to recursion. Bravo.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will try to apply them to my programm

Comment: You would want to store $v0 in the stack for the sole reason of you don't absolutely know if its being used elsewhere. I was taught to store EVERY variable into the stack and remove it as needed for thigns like this.